# How to send Object via Ajax to Servlet

Tags: ajax, object, servlets

How do I send an element of type object via ajax to a servlet?
In the ajax I am passing the value as follows below:

```
data: { mapList : mapLists }
```

To get the value in the Servlet am doing follows below:

```
Object o = request.getAttribute("mapList");
System.out.println(o);
```

However, the returned value is always **null**. What should I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax datas by :

```
data: { 'mapList' : mapLists }
```

Comment: Hello guys, did both the amendments which you said, but the result remains Null. The following link has a print of the object that I want to send to my Servlet http://bit.ly/V9oHsg .. So guys, any other tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On HTTP GET or POST requests you can only send a list of key/value pairs as parameters to the server so you will have to manually serialize your object to send its attributes in this format.

You should better use `HttpServletRequest.getParameter(String)` in place of `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)`. Also, what you get as an HTTP GET/POST parameter will always be received in the servlet as a `String`.

I assume that you are using jQuery to send the ajax request. I also asume that your mapLists variable is a json object. As far as I know, jQuery doesn't automatically convert a json object to a key/value pair HTTP parameter list so you will have to do it by yourself and then parse it back in the servlet. You can use [JSON.stringify()](http://www.json.org/js.html) to convert your json object or you can serialize it manually.

Comment: Hello guys, did both the amendments which you said, but the result remains Null. The following link has a print of the object that I want to send to my Servlet http://bit.ly/V9oHsg .. So guys, any other tips? Thank you.

Comment: Hello Roberto Linares thanks for the feedback. [This link](http://pastebin.com/Nug8CpVm) contains the function which generates my objects (Arrays). [This link](http://pastebin.com/j99dXmLa) has the code how do I send the results via ajax and gets it in the servlet. With these results what I thinking was to pick up the values and puts them on a Map<K,V>;. Where the values out of the brackets are the keys and the values inside the brackets as values. By have the value returned in the following format "Disease":["name","class"],"Drug":["indication"],"GenericDrug":["affectedOrganism"]